# KiteSDK MapReduce: EOF exception during parquet file load

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, parquet

I have hadoop map-reduce job which uses **KitSDK DatasetKeyInputFormat**. It is configured to read parquet file.

Eveery time I run the job I get following exception:

> Error: java.io.EOFException
>           at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
>           at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
>           at parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputSplit.readArray(ParquetInputSplit.java:304)
>           at parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputSplit.readFields(ParquetInputSplit.java:263)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:71)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:372)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:754)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

The same file can be successfully read by map-reduce jobs created by hive. I.e. I can query it successfully.

To isolate possible issue I have created map-reduce job based on the [KiteSDK example for mapreduce](https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite/blob/master/kite-data/kite-data-mapreduce/src/test/java/org/kitesdk/data/mapreduce/TestMapReduce.java). But I still get the same exception.

Note: AVRO and CSV formats work well.